# pyspark : how to check if a file exists in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, filesystems, hdfs, pyspark

I want to check if several files exist in hdfs before load them by SparkContext.
I use pyspark. I tried 
`os.system("hadoop fs -test -e %s" %path)`
but as I have a lot of paths to check, the job crashed.
I tried also `sc.wholeTextFiles(parent_path)` and then filter by keys. but it crashed also because the parent_path contains a lot of sub paths and files.
Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Rigth how it says [Tristan Reid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1575163/tristan-reid):

> ...(Spark) It can read many formats, and it supports Hadoop glob expressions, which are terribly useful for reading from multiple paths in HDFS, but it doesn't have a builtin facility that I'm aware of for traversing directories or files, nor does it have utilities specific to interacting with Hadoop or HDFS.

Anyway, this is his answer to a related question: [Pyspark: get list of files/directories on HDFS path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35750614/pyspark-get-list-of-files-directories-on-hdfs-path)

Once you have the list of files in a directory, it is easy to check if a particular file exist.

I hope it can help somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [pydoop](https://crs4.github.io/pydoop/api_docs/hdfs_api.html#hdfs-api)? The `exists` function should work

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you can use `hadoop fs -lsr your_path` to get all the paths, and then check if the paths you're interested in are in that set.

Regarding your crash, it's possible it was a result of all the calls to `os.system`, rather than being specific to the hadoop command.  Sometimes calling an external process can result in issues related to buffers that are never getting released, in particular I/O buffers (stdin/stdout).

One solution would be to make a single call to a bash script that loops over all the paths.  You can create the script using a string template in your code, fill in the array of paths in the script, write it, then execute.

It may also be a good idea to switch to the `subprocess` module of python, which gives you more granular control over handling subprocesses.  Here's the equivalent of `os.system`:

```
process = subprocess.check_output(
        args=your_script,
        stdout=PIPE,
        shell=True
    )
```

Note that you can switch `stdout` to something like a file handle if that helps you with debugging or making the process more robust.  Also you can switch that `shell=True` argument to `False` unless you're going to call an actual script or use shell-specific things like pipes or redirection.