# Pyspark: get list of files/directories on HDFS path

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

As per title. I'm aware of `textFile` but, as the name suggests, it works only on text files.
I would need to access files/directories inside a path on either HDFS or a local path. I'm using pyspark.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe it's helpful to think of Spark only as a data processing tool, with a domain that begins at loading the data.  It can read many formats, and it supports Hadoop glob expressions, which are terribly useful for reading from multiple paths in HDFS, but it doesn't have a builtin facility that I'm aware of for traversing directories or files, nor does it have utilities specific to interacting with Hadoop or HDFS.

There are a few available tools to do what you want, including [esutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/esutil) and [hdfs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hdfs/).  The hdfs lib supports both CLI and API, you can jump straight to 'how do I list HDFS files in Python' right [here](http://hdfscli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#exploring-the-file-system).  It looks like this:

```py
from hdfs import Config
client = Config().get_client('dev')
files = client.list('the_dir_path')
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please guide me how to make that hdfscli.cfg file, i dont know what port number to put it. 
[global]
default.alias = dev

[dev.alias]
url = http://dev.namenode:port
user = ann

Comment: 2nd @ShivamKotwalia as I cannot specify one user access to my EMR, it has to be fully dynamic and I am not passing configured users through my code

Comment: what I am support to put in get_client('dev'), I don't have the alias 'dev'

Comment: @HahaTTpro you can call that function without a parameter, it is only required if you have set up alternate aliases.  If you aren't sure, look for a file ~/.hdfscli.cfg, and within that search for `default.alias`

Answer (score 71):

Using JVM gateway maybe is not so elegant, but in some cases the code below could be helpful:

```py
URI           = sc._gateway.jvm.java.net.URI
Path          = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
FileSystem    = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
Configuration = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration


fs = FileSystem.get(URI("hdfs://somehost:8020"), Configuration())

status = fs.listStatus(Path('/some_dir/yet_another_one_dir/'))

for fileStatus in status:
    print(fileStatus.getPath())
```

Comment: use `globStatus` instead of `fileStatus` if you want to filter the results, e.g. `status = fs.globStatus(Path('/some_dir/yet_another_one_dir/*.csv'))`

Comment: This is quite good since it doesn't require me to upload additional libraries to spark-submit.

Comment: What is a good way to get/lookup `somehost`, i.e., the namenode, in pyspark?

Comment: I have thousands of files, and this piece of code `files = [file.getPath() for file in status]` takes a while. Is it normal? I'd say this is not the best efficent way.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx I think you meant to say to use `globStatus` instead of `listStatus`, not `fileStatus` (which is just a temp variable).

Comment: This was great Thanks .. and kudos

Answer (score 18):

If you use [PySpark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/programming-guide.html), you can execute commands *interactively*:

---

List all files from a chosen directory:

`hdfs dfs -ls <path>` e.g.: `hdfs dfs -ls /user/path`:

```py
import os
import subprocess

cmd = 'hdfs dfs -ls /user/path'
files = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).strip().split('\n')
for path in files:
  print path
```

---

Or search files in a chosen directory:

`hdfs dfs -find <path> -name <expression>` e.g.: `hdfs dfs -find /user/path -name *.txt`:

```py
import os
import subprocess

cmd = 'hdfs dfs -find {} -name *.txt'.format(source_dir)
files = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).strip().split('\n')
for path in files:
  filename = path.split(os.path.sep)[-1].split('.txt')[0]
  print path, filename
```

Comment: Hi Shouldn't the
files = subprocess.check_output(cmd_find).strip().split('\n')
be 
files = subprocess.check_output(cmd).strip().split('\n')
I tried editing but SO said that the edit must be greater than 6 changes.

Comment: @Darius Morawiec: how to execute `hdfs dfs -rm -r` command? is it using the same check_output method or some other way?

Comment: @Shankar, for that you can use [subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) or [subprocess.check_call](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call).

Answer (score 6):

This might work for you:

```
import subprocess, re
def listdir(path):
    files = str(subprocess.check_output('hdfs dfs -ls ' + path, shell=True))
    return [re.search(' (/.+)', i).group(1) for i in str(files).split("\\n") if re.search(' (/.+)', i)]

listdir('/user/')
```

This also worked:

```
hadoop = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop
fs = hadoop.fs.FileSystem
conf = hadoop.conf.Configuration()
path = hadoop.fs.Path('/user/')
[str(f.getPath()) for f in fs.get(conf).listStatus(path)]
```

Comment: Your second option is the only one that has worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to read in *all* files in a directory, check out `sc.wholeTextFiles` [[doc]](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=textfile#pyspark.SparkContext.wholeTextFiles), but note that the file's contents are read into the value of a single row, which is probably not the desired result.

If you want to read only some files, then generating a list of paths (using a normal hdfs ls command plus whatever filtering you need) and passing it into `sqlContext.read.text` [[doc]](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.text) and then converting from a `DataFrame` to an `RDD` seems like the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to do this using snakebite library

```py
from snakebite.client import Client

hadoop_client = Client(HADOOP_HOST, HADOOP_PORT, use_trash=False)

for x in hadoop_client.ls(['/']):

...     print x
```