# Always read latest folder from s3 bucket in spark

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

Below is how my s3 bucket folder structure looks like,

`s3://s3bucket/folder1/morefolders/$folder_which_I_want_to_pick_latest/`

`$folder_which_I_want_to_pick_latest` - This folder can always have an incrementing number for every new folder that comes in, like `randomnumber_timestamp`

Is there a way I can automate this process by always reading the most recent folder in s3 from spark in Scala

Comment: Not voting to close but this could be an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50526076/find-latest-file-pyspark

Comment: Might be a good example for choosing latest file, But I am looking among latest folders which have files in them as parquet. Also I would require scala solution

Answer (score 2):

The best way to work with that kind of "behavior" is structure your data as a partitioned approach, like `year=2020/month=02/day=12`, where, every partition is a folder (in `aws-console`). In this way you can use a simple `filter` on `spark` to determine the latest one. (more info: https://www.datio.com/iaas/understanding-the-data-partitioning-technique/)

However, if you are not allowed to re-structure your bucket, the solution could be costly if you don't have a specific identifier and/or reference that you can use to calculate your newest folder. Remember, that in `s3` you don't have a concept of folder, you have only an `object key` (here is where you see the `/` and in `aws console` can be visualized as folders), so, to calculate the highest incremental id in `$folder_which_I_want_to_pick_latest` will eventually check in all the objects stored in the bucket and every object-request in s3 costs. More info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/using-folders.html.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option. Consider writing a Lambda function that either runs on a schedule (say if you knew that your uploads always happen between 1pm and 4pm) or is triggered by an S3 object upload (so it happens for every object uploaded to `folder1/morefolders/`).

The Lambda would write the relevant part(s) of the S3 object prefix into a simple DynamoDB table. The client that needs to know the latest prefix would read it from DynamoDB.