# How to access org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy() from Pyspark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hdfs

I am trying to do some file operations of hdfs directly within a Pyspark Script. In particular I want to check

1. does a path or a file exits (`org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem`) --> ok
2. create folders/delete folders (`org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem`) --> ok
3. move files from one path to another (`org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil`)--> FAILS - WHY

So my issue is only in the use of the last class
My Code

```
# get all the jvm Objects
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

hadoopPath = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
hadoopConfiguration = spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoopFs   = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(hadoopConfiguration)

# this import does not throw an error so far
hadoopFu   = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil
```

the following functions working like charme

```
path1="hdfs://mycluster/somefolder"
path2="hdfs://mycluster/newfolder"

# check if folder exits and contains parquet files (returns list with or without files)
hadoopFs.globStatus(hadoopPath(path + "/*.parquet"))

# alternativ check only if path exists (returns true, false)
hadoopFs.exists(hadoopPath(path))

# create folder on hdfs
hadoopFs.mkdirs(hadoopPath(path2))
```

But as soon as I want to access methods from `FileUtil` there are not found. But I do not understand why, they should be part of standard hadoop/spark libraries
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.5/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html
The following commands are failing

```
hadoopFu.list(path1)

Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method list([class java.lang.String]) does not exist
```

also

```
hadoopFu.copy(path1,path2)

Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method copy([class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String]) does not exist
```

Why are they not found? I don't understand what I am doing wrong.
Important, I want to do this within Python/Pyspark wrapper
Thanks Alex

Comment: I'd suggest using pyarrow or pyhdfs if you're not actually using Spark functions

Comment: I also thought about using pyarrow on the driver only, but this would be not directly processed distributed on the hadoop cluster and would take some time to process all files. Distributing pyarrow via Dask on a Hadoop Cluster seems also quit challenging in particular without admin access to the infrastructure

Comment: You can use Oozie shell action to distribute the job via YARN. You could also use `subprocess.call(['hdfs', '-ls'])`, for example, or use `distcp` for copying

Answer (score 0):

For this answer, I'm looking at the Hadoop version that is used in the latest Spark version (`v3.4.0` at the time of this post): [version 3.3.4](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/87a5442f7ed96b11051d8a9333476d080054e5a0/pom.xml#L122) (commit hash `a585a73c3e0`).

If you look at the function signature of [`FileUtil.list`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/a585a73c3e02ac62350c136643a5e7f6095a3dbb/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.java#L1453)

```java
public static String[] list(File dir) throws IOException {
```

and of [`FileUtil.copy`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/a585a73c3e02ac62350c136643a5e7f6095a3dbb/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.java#L336-L509) (there are multiple ones, you'll have to choose):

```java
public static boolean copy(FileSystem srcFS, Path src,
                           FileSystem dstFS, Path dst,
                           boolean deleteSource,
                           Configuration conf) throws IOException {
```

or

```java
public static boolean copy(FileSystem srcFS, Path[] srcs,
                           FileSystem dstFS, Path dst,
                           boolean deleteSource,
                           boolean overwrite, Configuration conf)
                           throws IOException {
```

or a few others.

You can start understanding what is going wrong: you are not supplying the correct input parameters. `FileUtil.list` for example needs one input parameter of type `File` but you are supplying an input parameter of type `String` (`path1` is a String).

I'm not super familiar with making Java objects inside of Pyspark with the underlying `_jvm` object but try to make a `java.io.File` and give that as input to the `FileUtil.list` function, something like this maybe?

```py
hadoopFu.list(spark._jvm.java.io.File(path1))
```

Comment: `java.io.File` is incorrect. Hadoop has its own Path objects. Also, Spark doesn't use trunk

Comment: Great remark about Spark not using trunk, I will adapt my answer to contain a relevant Hadoop version!

Comment: About `java.io.File` being incorrect, I must be missing something. If you look at the [function signature](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/a585a73c3e02ac62350c136643a5e7f6095a3dbb/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.java#L1443-L1453C59) and the comments right above it, it seems to be using `java.io.File` right? I must admit that I'm not very familiar `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil` but I'm interested to see what your take on this is.

Comment: `path1` is a string but I transform it using `spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(path1)`. from the docmentation I thought this is the way to go

Comment: So you mean the error `method does not exists` might be a weird output from the method was not recognized due to the different versions that are identified by the correct parameters. But the `list` function is unique, this function at least should work

Comment: Indeed, when you see a `method does not exist` output that means that the exact way you wrote that method (including the input parameters and their types) does not exist. It does not necessarily mean that there is no method with that exact name.

Comment: But from the code that you shared here, it seems like `path1` is a `String`. I'm seeing `path1="hdfs://mycluster/somefolder"` and then `hadoopFu.list(path1)`.

Comment: `java.io.File` might be "correct" for that API, but it is "not correct" for accessing/listing HDFS `Path` resources since that class is generally used for local FS only. So, I don't think `FileUtil` is the the correct class to be used here

Comment: Fair enough, I agree on that point. Thanks for your insight!

Comment: Ok, this was a stupid copy paste error to stackoverflow `hadoopFu.list(hadoopPath(path))`  
or in detail  `hadoopFu.list(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(path))` . But it does still not work.

Comment: Yeah so as @OneCricketeer and me were discussing using a `Path` object won't work here: you'll really need a `java.io.File`. But more important than that, it seems like `FileUtil.list` might not really be the API you want to use. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40258750/15405732) might be more what you want.